# How can I get formatting to indent my Razor (vbhtml) code correctly in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: vb.net, razor, visual-studio-2017, auto-indent

How can I get formatting to indent my Razor code correctly in Visual Studio 2017?

```
@Helpers.LabeledGroup("Label:", "infoBox", @@<text>
            <input type="text" id="infoBox"
                   data-dojo-type="app/widget/form/InfoBox" />
</text>)
```

Every time I hit CTRL-K, CTRL-D to format the document, the input text keeps getting indented farther and farther to the right each time I format the code:

```
@Helpers.LabeledGroup("Label:", "infoBox", @@<text>
                                                                                                                                            <input type="text" id="infoBox"
                                                                                                                                                   data-dojo-type="app/widget/form/InfoBox" />
</text>)
```

I've tried a few extensions, but they don't seem to help. I've also tried playing around with the formatting of the input tag (putting it on different lines), but that also doesn't seem to help. I've tried using block instead of smart tabs and switching to spaces instead of tabs. None of these ideas work, either. Any suggestions?

Comment: IME Razor automatic formatting is somewhat hit and miss. And when it misses you get effects like this. Do not depend on VS to keep you Razor code & markup formatted.

Comment: This is a real pain and as far as I can tell there is no way to disable this behavior

Comment: Upvote https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/171757/razor-formatting-creating-lots-of-tabs-in-vbhtml.html

Comment: Here's a new link to upvote: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/250443/razor-formatting-creates-one-extra-indent-level-in.html -- looks like indenting is still one level off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has finally fixed this issue as of VS 2017, v15.8.